# pandas >= 0.18 - changes to resample, how to upsample with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I was using a piece of code similar to the block of dummy code shown below to insert NaN values based on attribute IDs for missing days (i.e. days where there is no data for that particular attribute ID) in a timeseries data set.

The change to the resample method with `pandas 0.18.0` has broken this bit of code, and I can't figure out how to achieve the same behavior.

Code:

```
data = [['2010-01-01', 'A', 2], ['2010-01-02', 'A', 3], ['2010-01-05', 'A', 8], 
        ['2010-01-10', 'A', 7], ['2010-01-13', 'A', 3], ['2010-01-01', 'B', 5], 
        ['2010-01-03', 'B', 2], ['2010-01-04', 'B', 1], ['2010-01-11', 'B', 7], 
        ['2010-01-14', 'B', 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'ID', 'Score'])
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

#Insert NA values on days where there is no data for each ID
df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'ID'], inplace=True)
df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('D').reset_index()
```

Running this now gives `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`, which when I looked at the new documentation I understand why it's not working.

However, I don't really understand how the new resample method is working, so some clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give the same results as in 0.17.1. I had opened an issue about being able to do this. Will try to see if can make a nicer syntax for 0.18.1, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12486). FYI, you don't need to sort before handle, resample always will sort for you.

```
In [27]: df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').Score.resample('D').asfreq())
Out[27]: 
ID  Date      
A   2010-01-01    2.0
    2010-01-02    3.0
    2010-01-03    NaN
    2010-01-04    NaN
    2010-01-05    8.0
    2010-01-06    NaN
    2010-01-07    NaN
    2010-01-08    NaN
    2010-01-09    NaN
    2010-01-10    7.0
    2010-01-11    NaN
    2010-01-12    NaN
    2010-01-13    3.0
B   2010-01-01    5.0
    2010-01-02    NaN
    2010-01-03    2.0
    2010-01-04    1.0
    2010-01-05    NaN
    2010-01-06    NaN
    2010-01-07    NaN
    2010-01-08    NaN
    2010-01-09    NaN
    2010-01-10    NaN
    2010-01-11    7.0
    2010-01-12    NaN
    2010-01-13    NaN
    2010-01-14    3.0
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution (edit - never mind, Score was referencing the column)

Comment: Maybe I should ask this as a different question, but I assume the same type of solution is required for the changes to the rolling_* functions. I.e. what I used to be able to do for rolling mean `df.groupby('ID').Score.apply(pd.rolling_mean, ETC)` will have to become `df.groupby('ID').Score.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(ETC).mean())`